# Application crash during keyframe animation: -[NSConcreteValue doubleValue] unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewanimation

Application crash due to this reason `-[NSConcreteValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to`

Following code is used in my project and I search very and I get the reason due to transform but if I replace transform.scale to it then animation changed
help me!

```
[viewContent.layer addAnimation:[self getShakeAnimation] forKey:@"transform.scale"];

- (CAAnimation*)getShakeAnimation 
{ 
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];

    animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI * 2, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)],nil];

 animation.duration = 0.8f;
 animation.delegate = self;


    return animation;
}
```

Comment: there is not any problem with your code..its working fine

Comment: did u find solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding an animation for the keypath `transform.scale` (a `float`) yet are passing in `CATransform3D`s. You need to either correct your keypath or your input.